# Apple II color monitor displays everything in green

Tags: crt-monitor, apple

I have an AppleColor composite monitor (A2M6020) that only shows green-scale. The color toggle switch on the front doesn’t change anything. I have plugged the monitor into multiple devices with the same result. nothing looks visibly wrong on the inside.

[image: monitor at the color button turned on]

[image: back side of crt]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: That button right of the controls should toggle it between full-color and green modes. What does it do with yours? Here's a link to the manual: http://www.apple-iigs.info/doc/fichiers/AppleColorCompositeMonitorOwnersGuide.pdf

Comment: @Janka it simply shifts the picture to the right by a few millimeters. it still keeps everything green

Comment: I think the problem is with the video signal then. Unfortunately there's different FBAS video signals out there and old computer monitors can usually only display the single one they are designed for. That you can actually see *anything* is pure luck.

Comment: @Janka my apple iic displays in all green as well, which is odd because that is what this monitor is designed for. I’m trying to fix it for use with the apple, and the xbox 360 was just the nearest composite output i had.

Comment: Has this thing ever displayed anything in color? I wonder, maybe there's a series of "color" monitors out there which has been sold to the government for schools that has a green CRT as a cost-saving measure.

Comment: @Janka that was my question but when i looked up the crt model number it is infact a color one, and it has been green as long as i’ve had it but that’s only about a year.

Comment: Open it and take a photo from the back, please. So we can see the circuit board with the CRT tube socket.

Comment: I have uploaded pictures of the inside of the monitor.

Comment: It's a color CRT, as advertized.

Comment: I thought so. That must mean the color circuitry is broken.

Comment: Your next steps will be to grab your oscilloscope and start to follow the signals. :-D

Comment: Most likely the problem is with that board with the tube socket. Those color amplifiers can burn out from old age. Check the three transistors with the heatsinks first.

Answer (score 3):

From the moire at the first photo one can deduce that the tube does emit some blue in addition to the green.

While cable or video signal path issues may be the reason, there is also pretty much a common failure mode for picture tubes where the basic colors fade one by one.

In this particular case look like you have some blue and absolutely no red.

If this is the case, the damage to the tube is irreversible.

I the old times, one would try to improve the situation for a while by increasing the heating voltage of the tube. This may or may improve the situation and will be good for a week or a year, depending on your personal luck.